# Finding Markdown image tags with regular expressions (E486)

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-markdown

I have a document that contains lines like

```
![My title](/path/to/image.jpg)
```

This is the format for images in Markdown.

I have constructed a regular expression which I believe should be able to find the image tags:

```
!\[(.*)\]\((.+)\)
```

But when I try the command `/!\[(.*)\]\((.+)\)`, I get `E486: Pattern not found: !\[(.*)\]\((.+)\)`.

---

### Motivation

I am trying to do this to change how images are presented in my [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) static site. I want to be able to search and replace everywhere in a file with

```
%s/!\[(.*)\]\((.+)\)/{{< figure alt="\1" src="\2" >}}/
```

If it matters, I'm using Vim version 8.0.1283.

Comment: Please use the correct regular expression items for Vim. So if you want to capture a group, you need to use `\(\)` instead of `()` and for capturing at least one of the previous items, you need to use `\+` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 1):

I use "very magic" setting (`\v`) so that I can use normal regex patterns and not have to convert it into vim's awkward regex format.

First, I would do search as the original regex search term, but prepend with `\v` to enable "very magic" regex setting:

```
/\v!\[(.*)\]\((.+)\)
```

After testing it to make sure it is working correctly, I'd finally do search/replace operation by:

`:%s/`**`<ctrl-r>/`**`/{{< figure alt="\1" src="\2" >}}/`

- `<ctrl-r>/` will paste the original search regex, so you don't have to retype it.

Result will be:

```
:%s/\v!\[(.*)\]\((.+)\)/{{< figure alt="\1" src="\2" >}}/
```

Comment: In fact, `:s//replacement` uses the previous search pattern. No register insert necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[Vim doesn't require escaping of parentheses by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631687/8033766).

As Christian says:

> [I]f you want to capture a group, you need to use `\(\)` instead of `()` and for capturing at least one of the previous items, you need to use `\+` instead of `+`.

Using this modification, my regular expression becomes

```
!\[\(.*\)\](\(.\+\))
```

The parentheses which were part of capture groups have been escaped, as has the `+`, and the parentheses which were literals have been unescaped. This new expression works as intended.

My full search and replace is now

```
:%s/!\[\(.*\)\](\(.\+\))/{{< figure alt="\1" src="\2" >}}/
```